# How to unit-test an actor that gets a reference to another actor inside its method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, actor, azure-service-fabric, stateful-actor-service

I've got an actor that looks something like this:

```
public class MyActor : Actor, IMyActor
{
    public async Task<ICustomerActor> GetCustomer()
    {
        var customerId = await StateManager.TryGetStateAsync<ActorId>(CustomerIdState);

        return customerId.HasValue
            ? ActorProxy.Create<ICustomerActor>(customerId.Value)
            : null;
    }
}
```

I want to know if there's a way to test this type of interaction. We use the [ServiceFabric.Mocks](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks) library to set up all the scaffolding needed to create actors outside of a running service, but when it reaches the `ActorProxy.Create<ICustomerActor>(customerId.Value)` line, it throws an exception because nothing is really tied together like a real service would be.

```
System.ArgumentException
Failed to determine the current application, please provide application name.
Parameter name: applicationName
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Generator.ActorNameFormat.GetFabricServiceUri(Type actorInterfaceType, String applicationName, String serviceName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client.ActorProxyFactory.CreateActorProxy[TActorInterface](ActorId actorId, String applicationName, String serviceName, String listenerName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client.ActorProxy.Create[TActorInterface](ActorId actorId, String applicationName, String serviceName, String listenerName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject an ActorProxyFactory into the calling Actor constructor, and use that to create ActoryProxy instances. Like shown [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks#communication-between-actors-and-services) or [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/master/test/ServiceFabric.Mocks.Tests/Services/ActorCallerService.cs).

Then use a mock library to create mock proxyfactories. Like this one: https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks

Comment: I thought of that, but was hoping for a better solution. :) I just wish there were a way to "fix" the regular `ActorProxy.Create` method.

Comment: To be clear, that's not a bad way to do it, but all the documentation says "to get an actor reference, call `ActorProxy.Create`". This would change that and now there's two ways to do the same thing. I'm always annoyed when library authors don't think about how their static and/or extension methods affect application authors who need to write tests. :/

Comment: I prefer this approach, but there's also Shims from the Fakes framework.